# Unpack data in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am using angular js and php. I have an array to post in my controller from js file.  I have converted my array to JSON and tried to pass the data like below

```
var update = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: apiPoint.url + 'up.php',
                 headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
               params :{
                        alldatas: JSON.stringify($scope.alldata) ,

                        section : 'A',
               }
```

By doing this I am getting 414 status error code. The url is too long.
So I have tried JSONC to pack my data..
I use jsonc.min.js and have updated my code as below.

```
var update = {
                method: 'POST',
                url: apiPoint.url + 'up.php',
                 headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
               params :{
                        alldatas: JSONC.pack($scope.alldata) ,

                        section :'A',
               }
```

Now my data is passing through url and in my controller I get the data. But I can't unpack the data. Please help me to unpack the data.

Comment: Why did you pass data over url?

Comment: I am using the theme Cliptwo . ther we are coding like this. Any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the standard [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#) component, and the mentioned JavaScript object stands for its [configuration object](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage).

You should pass JSON data through POST, i.e. the request body, because the request [URI length is limited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers). The `params` option is serialized into GET.
So you need to move your data (`alldatas`) into `data` option:

```
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: apiPoint.url + 'up.php',
  data: { alldatas: $scope.alldata },
  // you might even stringify it
  //data: JSON.stringify({ alldatas: $scope.alldata }),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8' },
  params: { section : 'A' }
};

$http(req).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
});
```

For the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type you should build a query string:

```
var req = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: apiPoint.url + 'up.php',
  data: 'alldatas=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify($scope.alldata)),
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
  params: { section : 'A' }
};
```

The [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) superglobal is filled only for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` content types. The other content types are available via the `php://input` stream:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
  $obj = $_POST;
} else {
  $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $obj = json_decode($json);
}
if ($obj) {
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($obj);
}
exit();
```

Comment: no. in up.php am getting only section. alldatas is undefined

Comment: @athi, have you tried to check if it is there: `var_dump($_POST);`? Have you checked the HTTP request headers - does it actually send the POST data to the server? Maybe some kind of cache is in effect. Try to send a test string instead of `JSON.stringify(...)`. Maybe the argument (`$scope.alldata`) has invalid data (or is just an `"undefined"` string). The main idea is to move the data intended to be sent to the server into the `data` section.

Comment: @athi, added samples for both `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `application/json`